# How to add elements inside consecutive dictionaries that are stored in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am not able to add elements inside dictionaries that are stored inside a list.
I have thousands of rows of data, I am accessing each row as a dictionary and then storing them into a list.
For example, my list is:

```py
[{'Sr_No': 2, 'Fac_id': 'RDR', 'Subject': 'dcom', 'Name': 'Tanmay', 'roll_id': 59},
{'Sr_No': 3, 'Fac_id': 'RDR', 'Subject': 'dcom', 'Name': 'Shashwat', 'roll_id': 1}]
```

I have a list of data stored inside a variable named percentage

```py
percentage = [50, 100]
```

Now what I want to do is add a key-value pair to all the dictionaries such that data stored into the above list gets appended as key-value to all the dictionaries and
my above example becomes:

```py
[{'Sr_No': 2, 'Fac_id': 'RDR', 'Subject': 'dcom', 'Name': 'Tanmay', 'roll_id': 59, 'Percentage': 50},
{'Sr_No': 3, 'Fac_id': 'RDR', 'Subject': 'dcom', 'Name': 'Shashwat', 'roll_id': 1, 'Percentage': 100}]
```

Comment: is there one item in the `percentage` list for each item in your data list and they correspond based on index? If not, how do the items in percentage matchup with the items in your main list?

Comment: @JonSG I have created another function to calculate the percentage attendance of a particular roll_id which is in turn fetched by the Sr. No. of that row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
l = [{'Sr_No': 2, 'Fac_id': 'RDR', 'Subject': 'dcom', 'Name': 'Tanmay', 'roll_id': 59},
{'Sr_No': 3, 'Fac_id': 'RDR', 'Subject': 'dcom', 'Name': 'Shashwat', 'roll_id': 1}]

percentage = [50, 100]


for e1,e2 in zip(l, percentage):
    e1['Percentage'] = e2

print(l)

# Out[205]:
# [{'Sr_No': 2,
#   'Fac_id': 'RDR',
#   'Subject': 'dcom',
#   'Name': 'Tanmay',
#   'roll_id': 59,
#   'Percentage': 50},
#  {'Sr_No': 3,
#   'Fac_id': 'RDR',
#   'Subject': 'dcom',
#   'Name': 'Shashwat',
#   'roll_id': 1,
#   'Percentage': 100}]
```

Comment: Thanks, will give it a try.